# Python - extract all variables from a dict into locals

Tags: python, django, python-module

Is there a simple and elegant way to extract all variables from a dict to the current module locals?
I am using Django and we would like to load all values of the `local_settings.py` file which is something like:

```
DEBUG=True
KEY="VALUE"
NUMKEY=1
...
```

from a json, which will be compatible:

```
{ "DEBUG": true, "Key": "VALUE", "NUMKEY": 1 }
```

so I'm looking for a simple way to extract all into the local variables of the settings.py file.

EDIT:
so inside my local_settings.py I will have something like:

```
   JSON_VALUES = {...}
   # here i would like to extract all the JSON_VALUES to variables.
   # in the most elegant possible way :)
   # ex: DEBUG = JSON_VALUES['DEBUG']
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does _module local_ means? You mean _module global_?

Comment: Yes, I mean extract all the values from the JSON into the module global variables. @BoseongChoi

Comment: `for key, value in JSON_VALUES.items():
    globals()[key] = value`.   `globals` and `locals` are the same dict if you run this in the top-level of your module